# Why specify index range in order to write a while loop list in Python?

Tags: python, file, loops, indexing, while-loop

```
mean_temp.txt = 
city,country,month ave: highest high,month ave: lowest low
    Beijing,China,30.9,-8.4
    Cairo,Egypt,34.7,1.2
    London,UK,23.5,2.1
    Nairobi,Kenya,26.3,10.5
    New York City,USA,28.9,-2.8
    Sydney,Australia,26.5,8.7
    Tokyo,Japan,30.8,0.9

mean_temp = open('mean_temp.txt', 'r')
city_temp = mean_temp.readline().split(",") 

while city_temp[0]: 
    print(city_temp[0], city_temp[2]) 
    city_temp = mean_temp.readline().split(",")

mean_temp.close()
```

The assignment is to just print the highest temperature for each city (ex: Beijing, 30.9).

My first attempt at solving this problem was to simply write the while loop as "`while city_temp:` ". I still don't quite understand why I need to specify the index for the while loop to not make the "out of index" error. Why do I need to write "`while city_temp[0]:`"? I thought the while loop will naturally end once it reaches the end of the list... :( Would love and appreciate help on this thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it will always have an element of `''` at the end of the loop, so then split, it won't have an third (second element) in the list (this is what makes the error), only one element in there, which is `['']`.

So you have to do `[0]` to also check for the first (zeroth) element for conditioning if it's empty, basically if it's empty, `bool(city_temp)` will be `False` then it exits the loop

Note that `['']` is still `True` because it contains an element

Better code, only works on python 3:

```
with open('mean_temp.txt', 'r') as f:
   for i in f:
      print(' '.join(i.split(',')[::3]),end='')
print()
```

Unless in the top of the code you write `from __future__ import print_function`, then it will work

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! really appreciate it :) this helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is so that the `while` loop will end when it reaches the end of file, with which `readline()` would return `''` and gets split into `['']` with `split(',')`, at which point the index `0` is `''` and evaluates to `False`, so the `while` loop would end.

If you want a loop that ends more "naturally" at the end of file, it's recommended to use the file object as an iterator so you can use a `for` loop to iterate over it instead:

```
with open('mean_temp.txt', 'r') as mean_temp:
    for line in mean_temp:
        city, _, temp = line.split(',')
        print(city, temp)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! really appreciate it :) i'll try it with a for loop as well <3

Answer (score 1):

The `[0]` you're using isn't the index of the line in the file, it's the index of the first element of the tuple you get by splitting one line on its commas. The reason you're checking that element is to recognize when there are no more lines.

A simpler and more idiomatic approach would be like this:

```
with open('file.csv') as csvDataFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
    for row in csvReader:
        # do something with row
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Because when you reach the end of your file, `mean_temp.readline()` will return the empty string, `''`. When you call split on the empty string:

```
>>> ''.split(',')
['']
```

It returns a list with the empty string in it, which is *truthy*

```
>>> bool(''.split(','))
True
```

However, you shouldn't be using a while-loop at all. Instead, use a for-loop:

```
for line in mean_temp:
    # do stuff with line...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! really appreciate it :)